# Export blender md2 with multiple named animations

Tags: blender, rajawali

I have tried to search for a solution for a while but it seems mystery no one have face this issue.

I want to export my animation built with Blender and try to export as multiple animations with name into md2 file.

and then import into rajawali on android.

however, I could not find the way to export md2 properly.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

First download the "MD2 exporter" plugin for blender. I have blender version 2.63 and have tried with various md2 export script plugins, but not succeed.

Finally I change a little in Md2 export script for blender 2.8 and then I have done this. you can download it: http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/398883/md2-export-rar.html (link expired, it needs to be refreshed)

Open text editor in blender and drop down the `md2_export.py` into text editor using mouse right click. Then press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to run the script.

Make or open your animated 3d model. You can naming and splitting you animation using NLA editor.

Please watch this video on how to use NLA editor :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBRqmeErOHU

To naming your animation. Add Nla tracks and define your animations length.

Name Nla tracks in properties (press <kbd>n</kbd> to show properties). After naming your animations, export md2 file.

Note that your model must have a single UV map. The UV map is necessary to show texture on the model in rajawali framework.

Hope this helps.